# The Replace() function doesn't work in a DataFrame column

Tags: python, replace, str-replace

So I have a column (`cylinders`) that has several values I want to change:

```
database['cylinders'].unique()
```

Output:

```
array(['8 cylinders', '4 cylinders', '6 cylinders', nan, '4 cylinder',
       '6 cylinder', '10 cylinders', '12 cylinders', '5 cylinders',
       '3 cylinders', '8 cylinder', '3 cylinder', 'other', '5 cylinder',
       '10 cylinder', '7 cylinder', '2 cylinder', '12 cylinder'],
      dtype=object)
```

I want to unify the values under the word "cylinders" and I thought of adding an "s" the values that have "cylinder" without and "s". So I tried to use replace() but it doesn't work and I don't know why:

```
database.replace(to_replace='cylinder', value='cylinders', inplace= True)
database['cylinders'].unique()
```

Output:

```
array(['8 cylinders', '4 cylinders', '6 cylinders', nan, '4 cylinder',
       '6 cylinder', '10 cylinders', '12 cylinders', '5 cylinders',
       '3 cylinders', '8 cylinder', '3 cylinder', 'other', '5 cylinder',
       '10 cylinder', '7 cylinder', '2 cylinder', '12 cylinder'],
      dtype=object)
```

Am I doing something wrong? I tried both `database.replace` and `database['cylinders'].replace` but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Is database a pd.DataFrame? It isn't mentioned and does not appear in tags..

Comment: yes it is a pd.DataFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace()` function is not an in-place operation. You'll have to provide `inplace=True` or reassign it to the original dataframe.

```
database.replace(to_replace='cylinder', value='cylinders', inplace=True)
database['cylinders'].unique()
```

Comment: It is still not working. Output: array(['8 cylinders', '4 cylinders', '6 cylinders', nan, '4 cylinder',
       '6 cylinder', '10 cylinders', '12 cylinders', '5 cylinders',
       '3 cylinders', '8 cylinder', '3 cylinder', 'other', '5 cylinder',
       '10 cylinder', '7 cylinder', '2 cylinder', '12 cylinder'],
      dtype=object any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This should work mate. Could be a bug in the older version. Update pandas and give it a shot.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help!